# reset CSS affecting inline styling and table attributes

Tags: html, css

I have
**reset.css**

```
/* Resets default browser CSS. */

html, body, div, span, object, iframe,

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,

a, abbr, acronym, address, code,

del, dfn, em, img, q, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,

fieldset, form, label, legend,

table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

  border: 0;

  font-weight: inherit;

  font-style: inherit;

  font-size: 100%;

  font-family: inherit;

  vertical-align: baseline;

}



/* Tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup. */

table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0; }

caption, th, td { text-align: left; font-weight: normal; }

table, td, th { vertical-align: middle; }



/* Remove possible quote marks (") from <q>, <blockquote>. */

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after { content: ""; }

blockquote, q { quotes: "" ""; }
```

My problem is that when I am applying some styles most importantly cell-padding on a table, these are not being applied. A style which I am applying is :

```
<table class='roaming-table' width='310' cellpadding='6' cellspacing='0' border='0' style='border-color:#00abbd; border-width:0px; border-style:solid; padding:3px'>
```

If I inspect the web page and untick the reset styles, mystyle will be applied accordingly.

PS I cannot remove the `reset.css` as this is doing other things in other areas

### The fiddle can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/AAr9N/

Would someone help me out figure in solving this issue.

Comment: try to make a jsfiddle to replicate the problem

Comment: I started a jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/AAr9N/

Comment: @Bobby5193 I didn't make a fiddle as this is a Wordpress php template which is getting data from a database and it would ruin the whole style if I would try a fiddle

Comment: well just add some dummy data instead to simulate what you have there

Comment: so what styles should be loaded ? are you talking about the border only ?

Comment: @Bobby5193 the cell-padding is not loading

Comment: so you need padding for the td's? It's not really a good idea to use cellpadding if you have a reset css. just add the padding in the css and not in the table definition.

Comment: cellpadding is overwritten by the td and tr styles

Comment: @sfyn how can I fix the overwriting ?

Comment: You need to use css to change the cell padding - by adding a padding attribute to `<td>`s, see my second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23083530/2671237

Comment: did you want a border? because border-width is 0px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do all this in a separate style sheet you can use these rules:

```
table.roaming-table {
    border: 10px solid #00abbd; 
    padding: 3px; 
    width: 310px;
}

table.roaming-table td {
    padding: 6px;
}
```

You can include these in a `<style>` tag on the page, too.

Answer (score 2):

If it's the cellpadding property you need, it would be better to just use css for layout and positioning if you already have a reset css file loading on your page.

you could add this :

```
.roaming-table td
{
    padding:6px;

}
```

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AAr9N/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try to not use inline style, because that will apply all time. Or you can try to add the !important property for all attributes, but i don't think this is the correct way, and i'm not sure it will work anyway.

Comment: Agreed, inline style should override.

Answer (score 1):

**Add css in your own stylesheet and that css file add in header after reset.css**

**To Overwrite the reset css file**

```
table.roaming-table {
   width: 310px; /* Add your css */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with the border is that a border width property is missing from your style declaration.

Try:

```
<table class='roaming-table' width='310' cellpadding='6' cellspacing='0' style='border-color:#00abbd; border-width:1px; border-style:solid; border-width: 10x; padding:3px'>
```

Or:

```
<table class='roaming-table' width='310' cellpadding='6' cellspacing='0' style='border: 1px solid #00abbd; padding:3px'>
```

Although as other commentors have noted, it would be better to do this in a seperate stylesheet.

Comment: there was `border-width:0px` in his initial declaration

Comment: @sfyn this is not case, border-width was there declared as 0. Its the cell padding which is not working

Answer (score -2):

Use `!Important` on the class name.

Comment: I have used !important on the styles applied in the class name however this still doesn't work. Also the inline styles are also not being applied